# Store list of checkboxes as an array of objects using redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

#### Intro

I have a list of toggable items (checkboxes). Each item may have extra fields with data. Here is a schema that is used by the server (request, response):

```
{
  medications: [
    {
      id: 'med1',
    },
    {
      id: 'med5',
      dosage: {
        units: 'mg',
        amount: 5
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- a value should be an array of objects
- each object may have an additional object-property with extra fields
- state of the extra property should be saved when toggling

#### Question

**What is an optimal way to implement a form that works nicely with data schema shown above using redux-form? Without a hassle of combining the resulting array of objects from two separate objects (sets of selected radio buttons).**

**Is there a more elegant way than a workaround below?**

*With my current implementation redux-form stores `medications` as an object of IDs as keys and true/false as value and I have to transform an array into an object when I initialize a form and transform it back to an array before sending to the server. While dosages are stored as a separate Form field, and I need to match medications with dosages and combine them into a single array of objects shown above. Such solution works, but is not elegant and adds unnecessary complexity*

#### Example of a "workaround" using FieldArrays

Recently I was able to implement what I need using FieldArrays. That's EXACTLY what I need but requires some effort to preserve data of deselected items as well as storing "manually" selected items to avoid performance issues when showing "checked" state.

This approach is much more elegant and does not require a transformation before/after form editing. And additional toggling/state logic can be separated a HOC component. The only thing I don't like is that I'm switching to the manual tracking of radio input state (checked/unchecked) by manually pushing/deleting an element from fieldArray.

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/jzjnjm4x3